# marshal protoreflect.MessageDescriptor

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am trying, in the line of [`google.golang.org/grpc/reflection`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/reflection) to marshall a  `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor`. The idea is to have a server serving `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor` to a client.

The client would use the `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor` with `dynamicpb.NewMessage` to instanciate protobuf messages.

I am not able to marshal `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor` because it does not implement `ProtoReflect()`. It does not seem to be possible to marshall it and "send" it on the wire.

Anyone has tried that already? Am I trying to do something forbidden by design in the go implementation of GRPC?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to be using [`DescriptorProto`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/descriptorpb#DescriptorProto) in your protocol, not a `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor`.  There are conversion functions in the [`protodesc` package](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protodesc) like: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protodesc#ToDescriptorProto